# setStatus of another Component in react

Tags: javascript, components, reactjs

I've looked through the active questions that are slightly related to my question but I didn't come to a successful solution. I hope someone can help me.

I have a simple react baby code on js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/10313/

Explanation of my code can be found below the code here:

```
var Test = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return{
            data: [
                ['Charlie', 10],
                ['Bello', 20],
                ['Wuffi', 15]
            ]
        }
    },
   render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <MakePOS data={this.state.data} />
                <MakeTable />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var MakeTable = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return{
            active: 0,
            weight: 0
        }
    },
    render: function(){
            return(
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Type</td>
                            <td>Amount</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Chicken</td>
                            <td>some</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Carotts</td>
                            <td>some</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Apple</td>
                            <td>some</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            );
    }
});

var MakePOS = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(){
        // update state of MakeTable Component to active = id of the clicked element
        // also update state of MakeTable Component to weight = data-weight value
    },
    render: function(){
        var POS = this.props.data.map(function(i){
        console.log(i[0]+' '+i[1]+' kg');
            return <button onClick={this.handleClick} data-weight={i[1]} id={i[0]}>{i[0]}</button>;
        });
        return(<div className="testDiv">{POS}</div>);
    }
});
React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('foodApp'));
```

To explain my code:

the state array in the Test Component represents the users input, in this case he choose to fill in 3 pets and their weight.

Dynamically to his input the buttons are created in the MakePOS Component.

Now what I want to do is, handle the Click event on those buttons and affect the state of the MakeTable Component in Order to deal with the values hidden behind that buttons.

I want to dinamically change the table rows amounts depending on the weight of the pet.

I hope its understandable.

Thanks for your help

**edit**
The facebook documentation mentions something similar, but I dont really get the hint of it.
In their example they are simply calling the onClick function in the same component. I can't find any solution for child component state altering of parent components :(
http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your `handleClick` function to the component which is managing the state you want to affect, in this case `Test`, and then pass it down as a callback via props.  Since the click is also affecting `active` and `weight`, they should be kept in the state of `Test` as well, so the `handleClick` can easily change their state.

```
var Test = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function(){
        return{
            data: [
                ['Charlie', 10],
                ['Bello', 20],
                ['Wuffi', 15]
            ],
            active: 0,
            weight: 0
        }
   },
   changeWeight: function(weight){
   // do whatever actions you want on click here
   console.log('I am in the main Component ');
   console.log(weight);
   },
   render: function(){
        return(
            <div>
                <MakePOS data={this.state.data} changeWeight={this.changeWeight} />
                <MakeTable active={this.state.active} weight={this.state.weight}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var MakeTable = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return{
            active: 0,
            weight: 0
        }
    },
    render: function(){
            return(
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Type</td>
                            <td>Amount</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Chicken</td>
                            <td>some</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Carotts</td>
                            <td>some</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Apple</td>
                            <td>some</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            );
    }
});

var MakePOS = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(weight){
      this.props.changeWeight(weight);
  },
  render: function(){
    var POS = this.props.data.map(function(i){
    console.log(i[0]+' '+i[1]+' kg');
        return <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,i[1])} key={i[0]}  id={i[0]}>{i[0]}</button>;
    }.bind(this));
    return(<div className="testDiv">{POS}</div>);
  }
});

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('foodApp'));
```

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for your help.
I have updated my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/10334/ 
I now get an error which says :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined
It seems to refer to the onClick={} Event in the bottom Component, but I am not sure

Comment: Yes I ve doublechecked it, the error occurs in this line : return <button onClick={this.props.handClick} data-weight={i[1]} id={i[0]}>{i[0]}</button>;

Seems that it doesnt refer to its component call in the parent component in order to alter the props and the function

Comment: The anonymous function within map needed a bind call to access props.  I added it to the answer and to the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qkz91124/

Comment: Thank you, the function call works properly now. 
May I ask you further? As you can see I've created a data-weight attribute to the button, is there a way I can access that value in the changeWeight function in the main component?

Comment: I edited the post to show how to pass the value.  Also in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mark1z/8c6aqmbL/1/

Comment: Well done, thank you so much! 
Is there any way to stay in touch with you? Seems like you really know what you are doing with react. I can't get the way to think "reactish" yet. I might need further help as I decided to do my universtity project with react :D

Comment: SO doesn't provide a way to direct message, but there are many people here who are great with react, so it would probably be most effective for you if you post your questions.  I'm glad you found my responses helpful!